# How do you assign a specific order for a category in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am having a small problem which I believe to be related to a syntax issue.

I have a specific script for home which calls the `bloginfo("name")` for the page title then an `else` statement below which titles pages based on the name of the first category associated them and it works fine:

```
else{
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   echo $category[0]->cat_name;
}
```

However, I also have a default "home" category for most posts(with a few exceptions) and I do not want this category to be picked up as the page title if it happens to come first in the list of categories associated for this page.

There are two ways I can think of making this possible but I do not know how to code them. The first would be to exclude the home category in the code above but don't know how to implement it. The second would be to somehow force wordpress to always add the category "home" after the first chosen category for a particular post.

I hope that this is clear. Anyone come up with a basic solution?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin does most of what you want out of the box:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-opt-in-front/

Alternatively, do something like:

```
function the_main_topic_link($link = '', $id = '')
{
    if (!$id || $id != get_option('default_category')) return $link;

    if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page' && get_option('page_on_front')) {
        if ($blog_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts')) {
            return apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink($blog_page_id));
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    } else {
        return home_url('/');
    }
}

add_filter('category_link', 'the_main_topic_link', 10, 2);

function pre_get_posts_redirect_main_topic($q)
{
    global $wp_the_query;

    if ($q !== $wp_the_query) return;

    if ($q->is_category(get_option('default_category'))) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/'));
        die;
    }
}

if (!is_admin()) add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_redirect_main_topic');
```

It'll treat linking to your default category as linking to your front page.

Comment: Hey Thanks Denis! I went the (sorry,lazy) route and the plugin seem to have resolved the problem really easily which is just how I like to fix these things ;)  But I will keep your script for future reference especially as despite being a php/wordpress newbie I am finding myself hacking through the stuff as I go along.

Comment: Note that the plugin (which I authored years ago) makes the front page a bit slow if you've lots of posts since WP 2.3, so YMMV depending on what you're doing. :-)